# React-testing-library wraps component with <div> which produces warning

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using react-testing-library to test my components. I have a TableHeader component which goes like this:

```
<thead>
  // rest of content
</thead>
```

When I test it with RTL to produce a snapshot or anything I get an error:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of

Finally I discovered that RTS adds itself a  around component and it causes the error. It can be seen in component's snapshot received by:

```
const { container } = render(
  <TableHeader />,
);

expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
```

SNAPSHOT RECEIVED:

```
<div>
  <thead>
    // rest of component here
  </thead>
</div>
```

Why is it happening? I didn't wrap whole component with `<div>` so it shouldn't be there...

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing really to do with `react-testing-library`. You can reproduce the problem in a simple React application:

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<thead />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

If you load this app in your browser, you will get the same error:

> index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of .

The issue is that you are not rendering valid DOM: a `thead` tag must appear under a `table` tag. The issue will go away if you add the `table` tag:

```js
// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<table><thead /></table>, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

As for where that `div` tag comes from, `react-testing-library` has to render your components somewhere, so it renders them to a `div` container, just like a normal React app.

In order to resolve this warning, I suggest you render the entire table in your test, instead of just the table header. Or if you wish to directly test this component, you could look into another library such as enzyme - I expect you may not get this warning with enzyme, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `options` for [`render()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#render-options). You'll find that you can set the container using something like the example in the docs:

```
const table = document.createElement('table')

const {container} = render(<TableBody {...props} />, {
  container: document.body.appendChild(table),
})
```